# Is it safe to run multiple COPY commands with NOLOAD attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to run muliple `COPY` commands against single table with `NOLOAD` attribute. 
According to AWS Documentation:

> NOLOAD
>
> ```
> Checks the validity of the data file without actually loading the data.
> ```
>
> Use the NOLOAD option to make sure that your data file will load
>   without any errors before running the actual data load. Running COPY
>   with the NOLOAD option is much faster than loading the data since it
>   only parses the files.

I know that it's strongly recomended to run a single `COPY` command against a table. But how about `NOLOAD` parameter? Is it safe to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation to use just one `COPY` command at a time is performance related. Since the data is only parsed and not actually serialized for insert this concern is not relevant. You could run multiple `COPY` commands at once without performance penalty using the `NOLOAD` flag. You can also use `NOLOAD` with a manifest.